# python-pptx - how to correctly fill in a shape with custom rgb colors?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to accomplish the simple task of coloring a text field with a custom color.
-> Not a Theme-Color, such as ACCENT_1 for example.

Following a small code example:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import ColorFormat, RGBColor
```

```
prs = Presentation(r"C:\Users\path_to_template.pptx")
slides = prs.slides

shapes = slides[11].shapes
for shape in shapes:

    if shape.name == "stufe_cred_1":
        shape.fill.solid()
        shape.fill.fore_color.RGB  = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
        break

prs.save(r"C:\Users\path_to_export.pptx")
```

So on slide 12, I am trying to fill in the shape with the name "stufe_cred_1" with the solid color red.

- What instead is produced is a black colored fill: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iBwu.png)
- While it appears to be set as a white background color: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZGGF.png)

Any Ideas on how i could fill it in successfully with custom RGB-Colors?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the solution makes me feel dumb.

```
shape.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
```

the ".RGB" just had to be lowercase.

Thanks to everyone who had started thinking about this!!